# Convert office files (Excel spreadsheets, Word documents, Powerpoint presentations) into images or pdfs in a PHP/Asp.net web app

Tags: php, asp.net, ms-office, office-interop

I'm doing a job for a client where I'm supposed to make a web application that can convert office documents and pdfs into a series of images, one per page/sheet. It's really easy with pdfs but much harder with the office files. So a solution that will convert the office files into pdfs is also good, I'll do the conversion to images later.

The environment will most likely be a windows server with the office products already installed (weird, I know)

Ideas I tried so far:

1. Using office COM objects - I ran into multiple problems and it seems inefficient and unreliable.
2. OpenOffice and unoconv - ran into problems using them on Windows. I may try Linux but my client says OpenOffice didn't work for them and I think I read somwhere that this solution is not recommended.
3. Aspose - tried it before realizing my client won't pay for it. It seems like the ideal solution but it's too expensive. So I need a solution without payed software.

Other options I thought of and didn't try:

1. Office interop dll - sounds ideal but people talk about performance issues and memory leaks.
2. Power Tools for Open XML (https://powertools.codeplex.com/) or DocX (http://docx.codeplex.com/) - libraries that sound useful but if I understand correctly they'll only work for docx files.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that Adobe offers this as a service?